# Get Last Payment From A User in SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have this table

[image]

I am trying to get the sum of principal + interest from the last transaction date. **Column 4**. is the last transaction performed - **[No column name]** is the transaction date

What I have tried so far:

```
select sum(h.principal+h.interest) as amt_paid, MAX(h.trx_date)
from Loanhist h WHERE h.ac_no = '$id' and h.trx_type='LP'
GROUP BY principal, interest
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you are looking for? because here you are using the aggregation function and also grouping them. so as a result, the database won't return the last transaction. we need to write a different query. If you would like to get only the last transaction then we can make the query.

Comment: @Rohit.007, I have edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test data generation is for Oracle, but you should easily be able to adapt it. The actual query will work on SQL server. You'll need to use an approach like this if the account can post more than one transaction in a day. Otherwise the 'LIMIT/TOP 1' approaches in the other answers will work fine.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE balances 
  ( ac_no CHAR(100),
    principal FLOAT,
    interest FLOAT,
    tranDate DATE
  )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO balances VALUES (1,123.123,.456,DATE '2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO balances VALUES (1,100,.456,DATE '2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO balances VALUES (1,200,.1,DATE '2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO balances VALUES (2,200,.1,DATE '2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO balances VALUES (2,300,.1,DATE '2017-01-02');

SELECT SUM
         ( CASE WHEN tranDate = max_tran_date
                THEN principal + interest
                ELSE 0
            END
         ) AS tranSum
  FROM (SELECT sub.*,
               MAX(tranDate) OVER() AS max_tran_date
          FROM balances sub
       ) BAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. But if you just want to get the last transaction performed by the user, the best thing to do will be to rely on IDs instead of dates.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Loanhist h WHERE h.trx_type='LP' ORDER BY h.ac_no DESC
```

Comment: I think you would want to order by trx_date not the ac_no. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 sum(h.principal+h.interest) as amt_paid, h.trx_date
FROM Loanhist h WHERE h.ac_no = '$id' AND h.trx_type='LP'
ORDER BY h.ac_no DESC;
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume the ac_no can't have more than one transaction in a day?

Comment: If there are multiple transactions in a day then the latest will be chosen.

Comment: It sounds like they want the last transaction date, otherwise no aggregation is necessary.

Comment: As per her description, She is trying to get the sum of principal + interest from the last transaction date.

Comment: Yes, last transaction date. That doesn't preclude transactions at 2pm and 3pm, both of which on the last day.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

try to use LIMIT keyword.For Example, Select * from table name where condition LIMIT 1.It will return first row